# How to search in firebase using query that has special charactar like '+'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am searching in firebase using orderByChild("telephone").equalTo("+11235123") and the value of the telephone in firebase is "+11235123" it doesn't work but Without the "+" it works.

Comment: Hi Ahmad. Post your data view too for better problem understanding

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also add the code that you are using for your query and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace the addListenerForSingleValue to addValueListner
because of the addValueListner gets one value and you may search for the other value

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of the field "telephone". If the type of the field "telephone" is number, adding the **'+' won't work**. **Make the type as "String"**, if it is not before.